# btrfs balance taking an indefinite amount of time

Tags: btrfs

I have a pair of HDDs I use for backup. They use a shared BTRFS filesystem with RAID1 configurations for data and metadata. The collective space is 4TiB in size and I've run out of space (currently about 20GiB left) and decided to convert them to data=single (I also back this data up to the cloud so I don't feel RAID1 is all that helpful). To perform this conversion I ran

```
sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=single -mconvert=raid1 /.backup
```

This converts a small amount of data in the first several minutes after starting and then does not progress from there. For instance:

```
$ sudo btrfs fi usage -T /.backup
Overall:
    Device size:                   3.64TiB
    Device allocated:              3.64TiB
    Device unallocated:            2.00MiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                          3.57TiB
    Free (estimated):             23.74GiB      (min: 23.74GiB)
    Free (statfs, df):            43.60GiB
    Data ratio:                       1.91
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:                 yes      (data)

                         Data      Data    Metadata System               
Id Path                  single    RAID1   RAID1    RAID1     Unallocated
-- --------------------- --------- ------- -------- --------- -----------
 1 /dev/dm-3              88.00GiB 1.70TiB 29.00GiB   8.00MiB     1.82TiB
 2 /dev/mapper/cryptsdb1  88.00GiB 1.70TiB 29.00GiB   8.00MiB     1.00MiB
-- --------------------- --------- ------- -------- --------- -----------
   Total                 176.00GiB 1.70TiB 29.00GiB   8.00MiB     1.82TiB
   Used                  173.39GiB 1.68TiB 14.42GiB 368.00KiB
```

The 88GiB was completed after several minutes, but the balance has now been running for several weeks. Neither `sudo btrfs balance cancel /.backup`, nor `sudo kill -9` is able to stop the process. The only thing that's worked is powering off the computer. I've tried this twice with similar results.

How can I successfully perform this conversion? I tried disabling the quota as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366227/293576) but without success. I've considered deleting some backup snapshots to free up space. Would that help?

I'm on Linux 5.12.4.

Comment: Anything in `dmesg` when that happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't recall. But I had a systemd service setup to create a new backup in /.backup periodically. After I cancelled this the rebalance worked.